# using worksheet events in ThisWorkbook class module

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a lot of worksheets, and want the below code to run when the event is fired by the worksheet...except I don't want to copy the code to all the worksheets

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$55" Then
         Target.Worksheet.Range(Range("A" & Left(Target.Text, 2)), Range("AE" & Left(Target.Text, 2))).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

so I tried the below in the `ThisWorkbook` class module, but I must have got it wrong, as it's not firing the event

```
Dim WithEvents xSheet As Worksheet

Private Sub xSheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$55" Then
         Target.Worksheet.Range(Range("A" & Left(Target.Text, 2)), Range("AE" & Left(Target.Text, 2))).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the above to run for all worksheets rather than specific worksheets, you could try using the `Workbook_SheetChange` event in `ThisWorkbook`. E.g.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$B$55" Then
         Sh.Range(Range("A" & Left(Target.Text, 2)), Range("AE" & Left(Target.Text, 2))).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this doesn't fire the event when I change the drop down in the cell B55

Comment: That is strange, because it works fine for me. Just to double-check the basics before going any further - are macros turned on? If so, does the event fire when other changes are made in any of your worksheets?